# Problemas con JQUERY DATATABLE

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

estoy haciendo una consulta por medio de `ajax` implementando `laravel` y `jquery`
pero mi problema es que no me  esta plasmando los datos que me trae, y en consola me dice este error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` pero miro en network y si me esta trayendo los datos, el problema es en el javascript que no me los esta capturando, se les agradezco su ayuda 
dejo codigo del javascript y el controlador

```
<title>Lista de Granjas</title>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}} ">
<div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="titulo">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Lista de Granjas</h4>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group container-fluid">
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Regresar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table id="list_granjas" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr style="color: white">
                    <th>Nombre de la Granja</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Direccion</th>
                    <th>Numero de Contacto</th>
                    <th>Porcentaje de Precebo</th>
                    <th>Porcentaje de Ceba</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var token = $("[name='_token']").val();
        $('#list_granjas').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/list",
                "type": "POST",
                "data":{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"}
            },
            "columns": [
                { data: 'nombre_granja'},
                { data: 'descripcion_granja'},
                { data: 'direccion_granja'},
                { data: 'numero_contacto_granja'},
                { data: 'porcentaje_precebo'},
                { data: 'porcentaje_ceba'}
            ]
        });
    })
</script>
```

funcion del controlador

```
public function listGranjas()
{
    $granjas = Granja::all();
    return response()->json(
        $granjas->toArray()
    );
}
```

Comment: Primera opción que veo en tu bloque de código es la url que llamas  que no coincide con la de tu función puedes probar un ajax simple  sin usar Datatables en donde veas que realmente se llama a tu lista de datos. Me avisas como te va.

Comment: pero en la ruta coloco esa url, olvide colocar la ruta pero si abro el inspeccionador y me voy a network ahi sale en nombre de la ruta con los datos que traigo de la base de datos.

Comment: Entonces el problema podría ser como trae la data tal vez sea dentro de una variable y justo por eso  te lanza el error de length. Revisa y eso y me comentas.

Comment: Haz verificado que $granjas tiene los campos especificado en las columnas de datatable?

Comment: esos son los datos q traigo desde la base de datos si miro en consola estan ahi